# C++ shadowing parent constructor

Tags: c++

Is there any harm in shadowing a parent constructor? It doesn't seem like anything is wrong, but my IDE is *indicating* and not warning me about it. Quick example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace NS1 {
 class A {
   public:
    A(){std::cout<<"I am A\n";}
    virtual ~A(){}
 };
}

namespace NS2 {
 class A : public NS1::A{   
   public:
    A(): NS1::A() {}
    ~A(){}
 };
}

int main()
{
    NS2::A a;
}
```

It works as expected, but... is it bad to shadow?

Comment: There's nothing particularly weird or odd in your code. This is just how you subclass a type. You're also not shadowing the constructor. Both `NS2::A::A()` and `NS1::A::A()` will get called as part of constructing a `NS2::A` object.

Comment: This is fine. So what is your IDE "_indicating_", then?

Comment: There is no anything like "shadowing constructors", since by default you can't use constructor of `A` to construct `B` which is subclass of `A`. There are constructors which are silently defined by compiler: copy constructor, default constructor, move constructor. They are disabled in some predefined cases. So your question has no sense.

Comment: What IDE is this and more importantly what compiler does it use?

Comment: Don't think that just because there are two things called `A`, there's shadowing. That has to be two things called `A` _within the same scope_. But you declared them in different namespaces and explicitly refer to `NS1::A`, so there's no potential for ambiguity or shadowing.

Comment: This is vxWorks WorkBench and the compiler is, pretty sure, Intel C++ Compiler 14. I just found it odd to see this indication and was wondering if it was a bad thing

Comment: Is there a text message with this "indication", or it just colors some code or similar marking?

Comment: Both. A purple arrow and a message that it shadows the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this code, except that it could possibly be improved by following the Rule Of Zero:

```
namespace NS2 {
  class A : public NS1::A {
  public:
    // Has implicitly declared default constructor, copy constructor,
    // move constructor, copy assignment, move assignment, and destructor.
  };
}
```

In fact, the constructor `NS2::A::A` does not "shadow" `NS1::A::A` at all.

A derived class does not inherit constructors from any base class by default. If you want that, you can say that it should with a declaration like `using Base::Base;`.

In your example, if `NS2::A` did not declare its default constructor `A();`, it would still get one implicitly with exactly the same behavior - but this is because a class with no user-declared constructors gets an implicitly declared/defined default constructor, not because `NS1::A` has such a constructor.  If we add `A(std::string);` to `NS1::A`, this doesn't make it valid to create `NS2::A("test")`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace NS1 {
 class A {
   public:
     A(){std::cout<<"I am A\n";}
     explicit A(std::string s) {
         std::cout << "Creating NS1::A from string '" << s << "'\n";
     }
     virtual ~A(){}
 };
}

namespace NS2 {
 class A : public NS1::A {
 };
}

int main()
{
    NS2::A a;         // OK
    NS2::A b("test"); // Error, no matching constructor!
}
```

And then, if we add a similar `A(std::string);` to `NS2::A`, that's a different function. Its member initializer list will determine whether creating the `NS1::A` subobject uses the `NS1::A::A();` default constructor, the `NS1::A::A(std::string);` constructor from string, or something else. But we wouldn't say that `NS2::A::A(std::string);` "hides" `NS1::A::A(std::string);` because the `NS1::A` constructor couldn't be used directly to initialize an `NS2::A` object even without the `NS2::A::A(std::string);` constructor present.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler/IDE *probably* means this:

```
  namespace X {
      struct A {
          A() = default;
      };
  }
  
  struct B : X::A {
      B () : A() {      // <- you can use just A, as opposed to X::A here
         A a;           // <- also here
      }
  
  };

  struct A : X::A {
      A () : X::A() {  // <- you cannot use unqualified A here to refer to X::A,
                       //    because it is shadowed by class's own name
        X::A a;        // <- neither here
      }
  };
```

There is nothing particularly harmful in it, because you can always use the qualified name. So I would say it makes no sense to warn about it, and it's a bug if the compiler does so.